# Cannot retrieve Authorization header from backend API

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using axios to make a request to my backend's login endpoint.

```
async function submitLogin(email, password) {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("user[email]", email)
    formData.append("user[password]", password)

    let result = await Axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/users/sign_in`, formData)

    console.log(result)
}
```

The output of console.log only shows me the "content-type" header and the "cache-control" header.

Weird thing is, if I make this request using cURL... the authorization header is there! My backend responds with a 302, and an Authorization header.

However, when making the request with Axios, it follows the redirect and then the Authorization header is gone. What the frick?